# Does Negative Test Cases Exists

Tags: testcase

I was attending a project review and the reviewer asked  me show project’s unit test cases, I said here it is. Then was asked for negative unit test cases…. Negative test cases??? Does it exists? I have never had one in 12 years of experience… do you?

I respect the reviewer as he added lots of value by his other questions but Negative UNIT Test… REALLY!

First question came to me was – do we have any unit test case which should fail to be passed? I mean its negative so it should fail… isn’t it? Then I started discussing it with peers and searching on internet. I got overwhelming results to conclude but still the question remains, how a “Negative Test Case” can pass to prove product’s quality? Shouldn’t it fail?
By now, my thought included the QA test cases as well. Let’s have some examples:
1.  Positive: Name field should accept only up to 100 alphabets – Should pass to prove product’s quality
2.  Negative: Name field should not accept more than 100 alphabets  - Should pass too to prove product’s quality
3.  Positive: Name field should only accept alphabets - Should pass to prove product’s quality
4.  Negative: Name field should not accept any special characters or numeric values - Should pass too to prove product’s quality
I can’t interpret 1 & 2 and 3 & 4 differently, Its same for me and all seems positive test cases to me(in fact just test cases which should pass… neither positive nor negative) . More over the outcome should be exactly the same for all to clear the test, i.e. – Pass/Green.

I actually failed to prove this to my peers and lost all the arguments – but “Negative Unit Test Cases” Seriously!!!   . Please share your thought and let me know if you wrote any unit test cases  (Dev) or Test cases (QA) failing of which made you happy.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because a test is negative doesn't mean it should fail. And in a way you're right - you *will* get the same "all-clear' or 'pass' or 'green' for all of your tests.

And you could say that positive and negative test cases aren't that different - you expect the program to react in a certain way, and if it does, it passes.

It's only in the context of characterizing the input or characterizing the behavior that positive/negative make sense. A positive test case gives the program what the program expects to receive, and passes when the program executes the expected behavior.

So a negative test case is characterized not by the test itself failing, but by how the program 'fails' or responds to errors or incorrect input.

The positive/negative characterization is just a convenient way to breakdown how to look at testing each feature to make sure everything that needs to be covered, gets covered.

When you use 'positive' in your question, you say "Positive: Name field should only accept alphabets". However, how you phrase this, this would actually be a negative test. You're not asking, "does the Name field accept alphabetical characters?" You're instead only looking at what it *doesn't* accept, and to prove that it *only* accepts alphanumerical characters, would require two tests, one to prove that it can ( the positive ) and one to prove that it will accept nothing else ( the negative ).

Properly, we have something more like:
Positive: The Name field accepts alphanumeric characters
Negative: The Name field does not accept non-alphanumeric characters

Answer (score 0):

Okay so....Negative testing is really just unexpected user behavior. For example, if a user tries to type a letter in a numeric field, If the Negative case works it should say "Incorrect input/behavior" Please enter a Numeric value..

As the testing thing... Well,It rather depends on which situation its in.
Such as if It was meant to fail or pass. The outcome would different.

Example:  More than 100 alphabetical letters or less than 100 alphabetical values. The "negative" test cases would be different for either.